# Docusign is not loading when opened through cypress test

Tags: docusignapi, cypress

I have an iframe with an embedded DocuSign. When I try to navigate to this page using cypress tests, the document won't open. I couldn't find much information on google. Is it a drawback in cypress that won't support docusign inside iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress has hard time working with iFrames; however, there are ways around it in most situations, which you can [read about here](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/).

The problem with DocuSign, from what I remember, is the document originates from a different domain than your test application. If that's the case, Cypress isn't able to test elements within a different domain, as it is [bound to a single origin](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs#Permanent-trade-offs-1).

If that is the case, I would see about using Cypress to interact with the DocuSign API directly and testing its integration with your application that way, if possible.